# Android: Using SimpleFramework to create an XML string and Encrypt it is not working with large files

Tags: java, android, xml, encryption, jce

I have an issue with my android application which only occurs every so often. I basically have a bunch of data in my database, which is converted to an XML String and that XML String is then Encrypted and saved in a file. The issue is that sometimes, when the file is more than about 3000 lines long, the file is corrupted, so when the file is decrypted, it has some garbage at the end of it, and some of the file is lost. I am not sure if the issue is in the encrypting of the String or in the converting of the Objects into XML. I have tried to reproduce and I cannot seem to understand why it only happens occasionally?

Below is the code

```
public static boolean exportDB(int wellnessDayId) {
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    WellnessDay backToXMLWellnesday = ExportDbToXml.buildXmlDataModel(wellnessDayId);
    if (backToXMLWellnesday == null) {
        return false;
    }
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    FileOutputStream fosbackup = null;
    try {
        serializer.write(backToXMLWellnesday, sw);
        DesHelper des = new DesHelper("12345678");
        byte[] decryptedBytes = sw.toString().getBytes();

        //Calculating the size that the array should be (ie multiples of 8)
        Double len = Math.ceil(((double) decryptedBytes.length) / EIGHT) * EIGHT;
        byte[] decryptedBytesPadded = new byte[len.intValue()];

        //Initializing to whitespace character
        byte whiteSpaceBytevalue = 32;
        for (int k=0; k< decryptedBytesPadded.length; k++){
            decryptedBytesPadded[k]= whiteSpaceBytevalue;
        }

        //Copying the array into the byte array that is the correct length (ie multiples of 8)
        System.arraycopy(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytesPadded, 0, Math.min(decryptedBytes.length, len.intValue()));

        byte[] encryptedBytes = des.encrypt(decryptedBytesPadded);
        String filename = "Export.blb";
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/export");
        dir.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(dir, filename);
        file.createNewFile();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        for (int p = 0; p < encryptedBytes.length; p++) {
            fos.write(encryptedBytes[p]);
        }

        Format formatter;
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss");
        String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
        //Create Backup file in /Wellnessdays/archive
         File dirBackup = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/archive");
        dirBackup.mkdirs();
        File filebackup = new File(dirBackup, dateFormatted + " - " + filename);
        filebackup.createNewFile();
        fosbackup = new FileOutputStream(filebackup);
        for (int p = 0; p < encryptedBytes.length; p++) {
            fosbackup.write(encryptedBytes[p]);
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("DatabaseExportToXML", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (fosbackup!=null){
            try {
                fosbackup.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("DatabaseExportToXML", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public class DesHelper {

public static int MAX_KEY_LENGTH = DESKeySpec.DES_KEY_LEN;
//private static String ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private static String ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "DES/ECB/NoPadding";
private static String ENCRYPTION_KEY_TYPE = "DES";

private final SecretKeySpec keySpec;

public DesHelper(String passphrase) {
    byte[] key;
    try {
        key = passphrase.getBytes("UTF8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    //The key is always 8 bytes, no need to pad the key
    keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, ENCRYPTION_KEY_TYPE);
}

private byte[] padKeyToLength(byte[] key, int len) {
    byte[] newKey = new byte[len];
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, newKey, 0, Math.min(key.length, len));
    return newKey;
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] unencrypted) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    return doCipher(unencrypted, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypted) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    return doCipher(encrypted, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
}

private byte[] doCipher(byte[] original, int mode) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(mode, keySpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(original);
}

}
```

Note: This is running in an AsyncTask

I do not understand why this is occurring only every so often, is there maybe a max limit on the size of Objects that the XML Serializer can accept? Or is there an issue with the size of the string that can be encrypted?

Comment: Even in ECB mode the end of the file is corrupted or just one block?

Comment: I suspect it might be an encoding issue and not the type of encryption as this encryption is working in some cases. Perhaps a special character?